# Randomly choose a symbol each time the document compiles

Tags: symbols, random, pgffor

I need to randomly change which symbol is attached to a particular command every time I compile my script.

I had hoped that this would be possible using the pgffor package, as in the minimal example below (where I am trying to redefine \add each time I compile):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\add}{\medtriangleright}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{\renewcommand{\add}{\pm}}{\renewcommand{\add}{+}}{\renewcommand{\add}{\cdot}}}
\foreach\x in {1}{
\pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{choices}
\choice\space
}
$$5\add4$$
\end{document}
```

However this doesn't work. This is strange as this precise code works fine when I try to generate a random number from a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\add}{\medtriangleright}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{1}{2}{3}}
\foreach\x in {1}{
\pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{choices}
\choice\space
}
$$5\add4$$
\end{document}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use the `\foreach` loop? It doesn't seem to do anything in your example.

Comment: As an aside, use `\[ …\]` instead of `$$ … $$` for display maths. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/87678

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the `\foreach` bit was because I was editing some other code where it was needed and didn't spot the redundancy before posting. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you don't need the `\renewcommand` macros or `\foreach` loop. You can also randomly change the operator mid way through the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{\medtriangleright}{\pm}{+}{\cdot}}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\op}{choices}
\[ 5 \op 4 \]
\pgfmathrandomitem{\op}{choices}
\[ 5 \op 4 \]
\pgfmathrandomitem{\op}{choices}
\[ 5 \op 4 \]
\pgfmathrandomitem{\op}{choices}
\[ 5 \op 4 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Every time I recompile, I get the same `\op`...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, that's weird. It works fine for me. Giving a random operator each time. Obviously some repeats with just four choices.

Comment: Now it is working!  I can't explain, but please take my upvote.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes [Maybe this is why it wasn't working](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: @Vaelus LOL that was magnificent.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `\renewcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

%\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\add}{\pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{choices}\choice}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{\pm}{+}{\cdot}}

\begin{document}

$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$

$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$

$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$

$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A much more intuitive version with `expl3` (not yet working with XeLaTeX, though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\add}{}
 {
  \clist_rand_item:N \c_matthew_add_symbols_clist
 }
\clist_const:Nn \c_matthew_add_symbols_clist { \pm, +, \cdot }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$
$5\add4$

\end{document}
```

This idea has more advantages, because it can be used in a “full expansion” context, which the PGF version can't.

Comment: Why do you comment out the random seed? Without this, I get the same outcome each time I compile.

Comment: @DavidPurton That's exactly for debugging. Uncomment it for the production version.